# Topology Munkres Lemma 31.1

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I came across this theorem in Munkres Topology 2nd Edition. But I am not convinced by the proof. The author defines $B:= X-U$. Certainly, this is a closed set, but I am not able to visualize how this can possibly be contained inside an open set $W$. Specifically, since $B$ is the entire space of $X$ but the set $U$, there cannot be any other set that contains $B$ and is disjoint from $U$. Also, I am not able to see the rationale behind $\overline{V} \subset U$.

Can someone rephrase this proof for me or help me understand the proof better?

[image: Lemma 31.1 of Munkres]

Comment: The existence of $V$ and $W$ follows by definition of a regular space.

Comment: @stange I get it but you should read my question more carefully

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if a set contains $X\setminus U$, then, unless is is equal to $X\setminus U$, there is no way that it does not intersect $U$. Fortunately, Munkres never claims otherwise.

What he does claim is that, since $B(=X\setminus U)$ is closed and $x\notin B$, then there are disjoint open sets $V$ and $W$ such that $x\in V$ and that $B\subset W$. So, $V\subset X\setminus W$ and therefore, since $X\setminus W$ is closed, $\overline V\subset X\setminus W\subset U$.

Comment: How is $B \subseteq W$ possible? There's simply no room for $W$. $U \cup B =X$

Comment: Also, throughout the proof, he is implicitly assuming $V \subset U$ without actually proving that.  Why is that not a concern for you?

Comment: Suppose that $X=[0,\infty)$, that $x=0$, and that $U=[0,1)$. Then $B=X\setminus U=[1,\infty)$. Take $V=\left[0,\frac12\right)$ and $W=\left(\frac12,\infty\right)$. Then $x\in V$ (that is, $0\in\left[0,\frac12\right)$) and$$B(=X\setminus U)=[1,\infty)\subset W=\left(\frac12,\infty\right).$$Do you see any problem here? I certainly don't.